# Successive iterations in one list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to create a list from elements of 2 different lists using list comprehensions.

For instance, assuming my 2 lists are `men` and  `women`, I want a single list with all names:

```
men_names = [man.name for man in men]
women_names = [woman.name for woman in women]
all_names = men_names + women_names
```

Is there a one-line solution to obtain this list? Thanks!

EDIT: Using a list comprehension is a requirement because in my particular case it should be very much faster than building the list in a `for` loop, and performance is an issue.

Comment: `all_names = [man.name for man in men] + [woman.name for woman in women]` ?

Comment: This isn't really a list comprehension problem; you can loop over multiple sequences and treat them the same here, because in both lists  all you are doing is access the `.name` attribute.

Comment: what are the elements of `man` and `woman`? Are they dictionaries?

Comment: @anishtain4: why does that matter? They are iterating over something that yields objects with `.name` attributes. It doesn't matter what type of iterable they have here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: He might not need a list comprehension

Comment: @anishtain4: perhaps, but that's not the question here.

Comment: @anishtain4: and besides, the elements *can't be dictionaries*, because dictionaries don't have `.name` attributes.

Comment: @anishtain4: Martijn is right, it doesnt matter for this problem. This is just an exemple and should not change the answer. By the way, i edited the post to explain why I prefer list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `itertools.chain` is a way to achieve this without creating an intermediate list.

```
from itertools import chain

all_names = [person.name for person in chain(men, women)]
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks! Now I just have to run a few performance tests to see if it's faster than the concatenation solution.

Comment: @LeNainXG since there is no intermediate list created, you will see that it is faster. Cheers!